# Document Root-Element "beans"must match DOCTYPE-Root "xml"

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, web.xml

I'm using eclipse for a web project using the Springframework and Maven.
As Server I'm using Tomcat v9.0.

To be honest I had a hard time configurating Maven and now this seems to be my last error:

> Document Root-Element "beans"must match DOCTYPE-Root "xml"

**What I have already tried:**

1. Checked my dependencies.
2. Deleted the .M2 directory.
3. tried several stuff like adding a  tag. Everything I Tried is manifestet in the code.

Would be great to hear something from you and thank you in advance.

**Console when starting Tomcat**

```
  Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: 
 Server Version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.16
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Feb 4 2019 16:30:29 UTC
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version number: 9.0.16.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            10.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architektur:          amd64
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Hersteller:            Oracle Corporation
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: 
 CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\wtpwebapps
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.5].
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFORMATION: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["http-nio-8443"]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["ajp-nio-5038"]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Server initialization in [1.883] milliseconds
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service [Catalina]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Fehler beim Senden der 'Context Initialized' Benachrichtigung an den Listener aus der Klasse [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 69; Document Root-Element "beans"muss mit DOCTYPE-Root "xml" übereinstimmen.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 69; Document Root-Element "beans"muss mit DOCTYPE-Root "xml" übereinstimmen.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 43 more

Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/Novega] startup failed due to previous errors
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1026)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:516)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

Mär 16, 2019 6:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:46 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [2.236] ms
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:48 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [2.066] ms
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [1.981] ms
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-5038"]
Mär 16, 2019 6:15:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in [13.349] milliseconds
```

**Spring-dispatcher**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.novega*" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Novega</display-name>
  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>350</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
    <listener>
   <listener-class>
     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>  
  </listener>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>     
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Novega</groupId>
  <artifactId>Novega</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-webdav -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-webdav</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api hier vorher nur Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
     programming implementation allowing you to define -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
     Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
     for web applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
     such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
     IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.astorm/jotlmsg -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.astorm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jotlmsg</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 




  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>WebContent/resources</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deletetd

`<!DOCTYPE xml>`

in the spring-dispatcher.

-Solved my problem.

Comment: You could also have changed it to `<!DOCTYPE beans>`.  It's supposed to identify the root element if it's there.